# Woocommerce load an external page on thankyou page

Tags: php

I am using an SMS API to send sms to customer on Thankyou page of woocommerce. The API redirects to the API provide's page after sending the SMS. I asked them for a solution, they suggested to use the iframe. But the redirection exists. Then, they suggested to call variables from page checkout. I am unable to understand. Kindly, guide me. Here, is my code.

```
function tz_send_message_to_customer($order_id){

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$currency = $order->get_order_currency();
$total = $order->get_total();
$date = $order->order_date;
$name = $order->billing_first_name . $order->billing_last_name;

// Configuration variables
$id = "xxxxx"; // Account Username
$pass = "xxxx"; // Account Password
$mask = "xxxx"; // Account Masking

// Data for text message
$to =  $order->billing_phone; // Recipient Number with "92" Pakistan Code
$message = urlencode("Dear " . $name . "!" . "Your following Order is Under Process" . "Order ID: " .$order_id . "Total: " . $currency.$total.  "Thankyou For Shopping") ;

// Prepare data for POST request - DO NOT EDIT
$data = "id=".$id."&pass=".$pass."&msg=".$message."&to=".$to."&lang=English"."&mask=".$mask."&type=xml"; 

// Send the POST request with cURL - DO NOT EDIT
//header("location:http://ip-address/api/sendsms.php?".$data);
$url = "http://ip-address/api/sendsms.php?".$data;  
?>
<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>"></iframe>
<?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'tz_send_message_to_customer', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution by searching on Google. It was suggested that use sandbox attribute in iframe like  sandbox="allow-same-origin". So, the iframe code looks like as

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style=" display: none;"></iframe>
```

More info can be found at: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/